# python : case of opening a file

Tags: python

code :

```
f = open('workfile', 'r')   Line #1
if f != None :              Line #2
     print f.read()         Line #3
```

workfile is not there in the directory, so understandably python create one.(Although in python documentation they did not mention it ). ok

but when i change the file name from 'workfile to 'names 'with same code

```
 f = open('names', 'r')   Line #1
```

**it shows IOError : No such file or directory.**

why didn't it created another file of 'names' ? as it did in case of 'workfile'

Comment: No, opening a file for reading does *not* create it if it doesn't exist. It'll throw an exception instead. Your `workfile` already exists if it doesn't.

Comment: in the first line you're opening 'workfile', not 'workfile.txt'! Be sure that file extensions are shown (in case of Windows)...

Comment: Line 2 is not necessary.  You just assigned a file handle to `f`, so of course `f` won't be None.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to open the file for reading using the `r` argument.

For python to try and create a file you need to specify the write command `w` like:

```
 f = open('names', 'w')
```

or if you want to append to an already created file you use the `a` command:

```
 f = open('names', 'a')
```

or for both reading and writing (will create a file):

```
 f = open('names', 'r+')
```

The [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) is pretty good to read up on too if you have queries.